# Zombie point calculations seem to be inconsistent

Tags: zombies, all-flesh-must-be-eaten

In All Flesh Must Be Eaten, I have been looking at a game that runs similarly to The Walking Dead series, but within about a month or two after the outbreak at most. The problem I am having is with creating zombies for it. The basic stats for a zombie seem easy enough to create, but I found an example online and do not understand how the author reached that point total.

The stats for a normal zombie in this setting would be as follows (including the point values listed in the book for those values):

> Weak Spot: Brain (6)
>   Getting Around: Slow and Steady (0)
>   Strength: Dead Joe Average (0)
>   Senses: Like the Living (1)
>   Sustenance:
>   ....Who Needs Food? (8)
>   ....All Flesh Must Be Eaten (0)
>   Intelligence: Tool Use I (3)
>   Spreading the Love: One Bite and You're Hooked (2)

This equates to the following:

> Strength 2
>   Dexterity 1
>   Perception 2
>   Constitution 2
>   Intelligence 1
>   Will 2
>   Dead Points: 15
>   Speed: 2
>   Endurance: N/A
>   Essence Pool: 10
>   Skills: Brawling 2
>   Attacks: As human, bite = d4xStr(4)

With the point values in the top section, it equates to 20 points, while the listing I see is showing 17 points. Is there some reason that this discrepency exists?

My source for this build is: http://www.edenstudios.net/WakingDeadFREE.pdf

Comment: It is a good rule of thumb that if the rule contradicts the example, it is the example that is wrong. This is because updating each example after every rule tweak is an error-prone process.

Comment: @gomad I figured as much, but it was a bit of a pain to hunt down information I was looking for for this game anyway, but I did look through the rules for zombie creation for both first and "revised" editions and the points were consistent with each other. In addition, since they are weak individually, a 3 point gap is very significant to determining appropriate numbers. I felt that because of all this, it was worth asking the question.

Comment: Oh, it was absolutely worth asking! I'm just saying that my experience both as a player and designer is that rules are more likely to be correct than examples.

Comment: @gomad It's also going to be the first game of AFMBE I have played or run, so I want to ensure that my ducks are in a row before I start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a typo: the accumulated Power is 20, not 17. Your calculation (Power: 20) is correct.

The following images are from pages 146 through 159 of *Unisystem - All Flesh Must Be Eaten 2<sup>nd</sup> Revised Printing*

## The Weak Spot

[image: The Weak Spot]
Adds 6 Power and 15 Dead Points.

## Getting Around

[image: Getting Around]
Adds 0 Power, 1 Dexterity and 2 Speed.

## Strength

[image: Strength]
Adds 0 Power and 2 Strength.

## Senses

[image: Senses]
Adds 1 Power and 2 Perception.

## Sustenance

[image: Sustenance]
Adds 8 Power.
[image: Sustenance 2]
Adds 0 Power.

## Intelligence

[image: Intelligence]
Adds 3 Power (you used Rank 1) and 1 Intelligence.

## Spreading The Love

[image: Spreading The Love]
Adds 2 Power.